# installing downloaded update for an android app without user interference

Tags: android, installation, apk, silent

We have some android devices at our customers' stations.
We Install our android app on these devices.
When an update is available, the app automatically downloads it and tries to install it.
The problem is that our customers have no access to their device so they can't confirm the installation.
I appreciate Any direct or alternative solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should require a custom ROM, where your app is pre-installed in such a way that it can update apps silently. The pre-installed app store (Play Store on Google Play devices, Amazon AppStore for Android on Fire devices, etc.) are set up this way. I do not know the specifics.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found an alternative solution to our situation (instead of installing a new apk).

Comment: @mohammad : try this link. it may help you  - https://github.com/RaghavSood/AppaholicsUpdateChecker